# Problems obtaining the serial ports of my computer through python

Tags: python, port, pyserial

I've been trying to get `python` to show me a list of the available serial ports on my computer. But `python` returns that there are no serial ports on my computer, which I find strange. Can someone help me?

Here's my code and what python sends back:

CODE :

```
import serial.tools.list_ports as port_list

liste_ports = list(port_list.comports())
print('Serial ports : ', liste_ports)
```

RETURNS :

> Serial ports :  []

Comment: this may be a permissions problem. check if you have the right to use the device.

Comment: Are you running this on a laptop? If you attached a serial device through USB and ran the code what do you get?

Comment: @NathanMcCoy I've launched python with administrator rights, wouldn't that mean I have every right on the device ?

Comment: @dgumo  Yes this is running on my laptop. I can't tell, I haven't attached a serial device through USB yet. I'm going to look into that, thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to then. Check if you can see the device

Comment: So I went and attached a serial device to my computer through USB. The eprogram now returns me the following list :  [<serial.tools.list_ports_common.ListPortInfo object at 0x000001F1296DC400>, <serial.tools.list_ports_common.ListPortInfo object at 0x000001F1291CA7F0>, <serial.tools.list_ports_common.ListPortInfo object at 0x000001F1291CA4A8>] I suppose these are the adresses leading to the ports ? But pyzo doesn't understand them, he still tells me either of them can't be found. Can anyone help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late here, but you can use the following script:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
List1 = []
for  port in sorted(ports):
        List1.append(port)

print(*List1)
```

By the way, if you use `List1` instead of `*List1` you are printing the wrong thing: `<serial.tools.list_ports_common.ListPortInfo object at 0x000001F1296DC400>`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue before. By checking the Win11 device manager, I found that its ports (COM and LPT) are located in the Bluetooth Device. I opened the Bluetooth option serial.tools.list on my PC_ Ports. comports() can output correctly